# How to add an expression and an arrow function to onPress in react native?

Tags: react-native, yup

I am trying to create a TouchableOpacity that executes another function and an arrow function, but cannot figure out a way to do so. Here is my code:

```
<SubmitButton
    text="NEXT"
    style={{ backgroundColor: "#093968" }}
    onPress={
        (handleSubmit,
        () => this.setState({ submitPressed: true }))
    }
/>
```

I understood that the second function is overriding the first, but how do I solve this problem. And I also don't want to add the arrow function to handleSubmit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
        <SubmitButton
            text="NEXT"
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#093968" }}
            onPress={()=>{
                handleSubmit()
                this.setState({ submitPressed: true })
            }}
        />
```